# change some property of objects inside a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a class contains List of several other classes.

```
class OuterClass 
{
IList<A> listA=new List<A>();
IList<B> listB= new List<B>();
IList<c> listC=new List<B>();
......... and so on ............
}
```

All these classes(A,B,C..) has same property called 'RowState'. 
Now I created two objects of 'OuterClass'

```
OuterClass outerClassOne = new Outerclass();
OuterClass outerClasstwo= new OuterClass();
```

After performing few operations on 'outerClasstwo' ,I want to copy the value of  the 'RowState' for all objects in object 'outerClasstwo' to 'outerClassOne'

I tried to create generic functions to copy property from one object to other and it is success full. but I have to call this function for each list and pass its type statically. Then  I try reflection to get list name and its type . But I am unable to pass type of list to my function

```
        public void CopyRowState(OuterClass fromOrderData, OuterClass toOrderData)
        {
            //this work for me ,but i have to call this function for every list in my class 
            CopyFromList< A>(fromOrderData.listA.ToList(), toOrderData.listA.ToList());
//working code end
            PropertyInfo[] classProperties = typeof(OMSOrderData).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in classProperties)
            {
                Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
                {
                    if (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
                        interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                        == typeof(IList<>) || interfaceType.IsGenericType && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))

                    {
                        Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        //want to pass list from here
                        //CopyFromList<itemType.GetType()>(propertyInfo.GetValue(fromOrderData),propertyInfo.GetValue(toOrderData));

                                                break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void CopyFromList<T>(List<T> from ,List<T> to)
        {
            if (from.Count == to.Count)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < from.Count; i++)
                {
                    Copy(from[i], to[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void Copy(object from, object to)
        {
            if (from != null && to != null)
            {
                string property = "RowState";
                PropertyInfo propfrom = from.GetType().GetProperty(property);
                var value = propfrom.GetValue(from);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfoTo = to.GetType().GetProperty(property);
                propertyInfoTo.SetValue(to, value);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you try `CopyFromList(outerClassOne.listA, outerClassTwo.listA);`? You can go from generics to reflection, though it's a bad idea. Going the other way,  to turn a `System.Type` into a generic type parameter, you'll need even more, and more fiddly, reflection code. You'd be better off rewriting CopyFromList() using reflection instead of generics, if it came to that.

Comment: Is OuterClass a class you have control over?

Comment: 1) Rewrite classes A, B, and C to share a common base class called `RowBase`, where the `RowState` property is Defined. 2) Rewrite CopyFromList as `CopyFromList(IList<RowBase> from, IList<RowBase> to)`, and do this in the loop: `to[i].RowState = from[i].RowState;`. 3) Call that method three times in `CopyRowState()` for the three different lists. No reflection, no generics, only OOP.

Comment: I have tried "CopyFromList(outerClassOne.listA, outerClassTwo.listA)" and mentioned in the question. Adding a base class is a hectic job here.There are around 42 classes inside and getting permission for such rework is impossible

Comment: That's a shame about the base class. What is the *problem* with `CopyFromList(outerClassOne.listA, outerClassTwo.listA)`, same with listB, etc.? There are 42 list properties on each OuterClass? Sounds like there's a corporate-level commitment to writing bad code. I'd just go with the flow.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why `Copy<T>()` has a type parameter that isn't used?